# inotify doesn’t notify the way I would expect it to

Tags: c++, inotify

I have created that little snippet to try and understand how inotify works. My test is very simple: I run the code, then open /home/qdii/test with any editor, modify it and save the file. Nothing happens. I modify the file again and save, and “event received” is displayed. From that moment, modifying the file again won’t trigger anything no more.

I would expect inotify to issue “event received” every time the file is modified. What did I do wrong?

```cpp
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const int fd = inotify_init();
    inotify_add_watch(fd, "/home/qdii/test", IN_MODIFY);

    while (true)
    {
        const size_t buf_size = sizeof(struct inotify_event);
        char buf[buf_size]; 

        if (read(fd, buf, buf_size) >= 0)
            std::cout << "event received" << std::endl;

        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected. Most editors don't (always) edit the file in-place, but create temporary files and play unlink/rename games on save (in order not to lose data).

Since you're not tracking file deletion events, you don't know that the file you're tracking has gone. If you want to continue tracking the newly-created file (with the same name) after your editor has saved, you'll need to remove the original watch, and re-add it (preferably following a watch trigger on file creation for the directory you're working in).

Other remark: that `sleep` in there is both un-necessary and counter-productive. The `read` is blocking, so you won't waste CPU when nothing happens, and sleeping increases your chance of missing events.

Comment: The `sleep` is a leftover from an unsuccesful former try with `inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK)` but thanks for your explanation :)

Comment: I just tested by using `echo a >> /home/qdii/test` and that proved to work fine .thank you again.

Comment: oh and btw I’m watching file modification, not file deletion. Not that it changes anything.

Comment: You'd have noticed the behavior if you'd been watching deletions too though.